# Use sed to replace a group match

Tags: regex, bash, sed

I have a simple regular expression that creates a group match for any semicolon contained within double quotes. I'm trying to use sed on Mac OS X to replace the semicolon with 'SEMICOLON'.

However, it's not working.

Here's the command I used:

`sed -i.bu "s|.*?(;).*?|SEMICOLON|g" output/html/index.html`

The result is that nothing is matched and nothing is replaced.

Desired behavior:

**Input**

```
"The man sat; the man cried;" cats; dogs;
```

**Output**

```
"The man satSEMICOLON the man criedSEMICOLON" cats; dogs;
```

UPDATE:
Thanks for your help everyone. So my example wasn't very good. In reality, I process a JavaScript file that's been condensed to one line, and make sure each JavaScript statement has its own line. The problem is that the JavaScript is mostly translated text, so trying to make a simple regex that would insert a newline after each `;` was difficult, because I obviously don't want a newline added if the semicolon is in quotes.

Long story short... I realized I was trying to reinvent the wheel, and decided to use `js-beautify` to `pretty print` the file. It's doing a little more than I need... but it's the best solution for now.

Thanks again!

Comment: What is the output you wanted?

Comment: "The man satSEMICOLON the man cried" cats; dogs;

Comment: Basically, I want to find all semicolons that are within quotes and replace with SEMICOLON. If a semicolon isn't contained within quotes, I want it to be left alone.

Comment: You're trying to use a PCRE which sed doesn't support. Use a BRE or, if your sed has a `-E` flag, an ERE. Do you REALLY have `cried;"` in the input and want it to become `cried"` in the output so semicolons between quotes get treated different depending on their position?

Comment: Can you have multiple quoted text sections in the same line or is it always just the one instance?  Ex: `"bla1;bla1" bla2;bla3;"titi;titi";toto`

Comment: You use capture groups for the part you want to copy to the replacement, not for the part you want to replace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sed is for simple s/old/new that is all. With any awk:

```
$ awk 'match($0,/"[^"]+"/) {
    str = substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)
    gsub(/;/,"SEMICOLON",str)
    $0 = substr($0,1,RSTART-1) str substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH)
} 1' file
"The man satSEMICOLON the man criedSEMICOLON" cats; dogs;
```

That's assuming you actually want all semicolons in the quoted string treated the same way. If not, whatever it is you want to do is an easy tweak, e.g. if you want that last semicolon after `cried` removed instead of replaced as shown in your sample output:

```
$ awk 'match($0,/"[^"]+"/) {
    str = substr($0,RSTART+1,RLENGTH-2)
    sub(/;$/,"",str)
    gsub(/;/,"SEMICOLON",str)
    $0 = substr($0,1,RSTART) str substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH-1)
} 1' file
"The man satSEMICOLON the man cried" cats; dogs;
```

Comment: thanks so much for this answer... seems to be a great solution, but it seems to break on larger files... I think this happens if the string spans multiple lines.... I wish I was more of a regex pro!!

Comment: Right, but the fix has little to do with regexps. Awk works one record at a time and the default record separator is a newline character. If your records can span multiple lines then you need to set the `RS` (Record Separator) variable to whatever is used to separate records instead of newlines. Obviously that would be a crucial example missing from your sample input/output so edit your question to better represent your real data and while you're at it clarify if the vanishing `;` after `cried` is real or a typo. Also tell us whether or not you can use GNU awk.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, the vanishing typo was my mistake... so, everything actually will be on one line, but this seems to only find the first quoted semicolon and replaced it. Example input: `"The man sat;" "The girl cried;" "The dog barked;"` , yields this output: `"The man satSEMICOLON" "The girl cried;" "The dog barked;"`

Comment: Again - it's CRUCIAL for your sample input/output to reflect your real data as what you show us is all we have to go on. You showed input with one string on a line so you got a solution for data that has one string per line. If you can have multiple strings on a line then, hopefully obviously, your posted example should have at least 2 strings on the line. So once again please edit your question to make sure your sample input/input truly represent your real data. And, again, tell us if you can use GNU awk or not.

Comment: Thanks again Ed... I realized that I wasn't really using the best tool to get this job done..... I strings were part of a js file, and I decided on just using an npm package to pretty print the js....  I updated my question.. but I'm going to upvote your answer because it was the best answer to my original questions.

Answer (score 4):

Let's take this as a test file:

```
$ cat file
"The man sat; the man cried;" cats; dogs;
1; 2; "man;"; 3; ";dog";
```

Try this sed command:

```
$ sed -E ':a; s/^(([^"]*"[^"]*")*[^"]*"[^"]*);/\1SEMICOLON/; ta' file
"The man satSEMICOLON the man criedSEMICOLON" cats; dogs;
1; 2; "manSEMICOLON"; 3; "SEMICOLONdog";
```

How it works:

- `:a`

  This creates a label `a` that we can refer to later.
- `s/^(([^"]*"[^"]*")*[^"]*"[^"]*);/\1SEMICOLON/`

  This replaces the last `;` that is inside double-quotes with SEMICOLON.  Let's look at `^(([^"]*"[^"]*")*[^"]*"[^"]*);` in more detail:

  1. `^` matches at the beginning of a string.
  2. `([^"]*"[^"]*")*` matches from the beginning of the line through any number of complete quoted strings.

     Because, in sed, regular expressions are *greedy* (more precisely, leftmost-longest), this will try to match as many complete quoted strings as it can.
  3. `[^"]*"[^"]*;` matches any non-quotes that follow the complete quoted strings (as above), followed the next quote character, followed by any number of non-quote characters, followed by `;`.

  Since the above regex minus the final `;` is itself inside parens, it is saved as group 1.  We replace the matched text with group 1 followed by SEMICOLON.
- `ta`

  If the last command resulted in a substitution (in other words, we found a `;` that needed to be replaced), then jump back to label `a` and repeat.

#### Discussion

Let's consider:

```
sed "s|.*?(;).*?|SEMICOLON|g"
```

In Python and elsewhere, `.*?` is a non-greedy match.  Sed, however, has no such concept.  For that matter, by default, sed uses Basic Regular Expressions (BRE) in which `?` just means a literal question mark.

Also, it is asking for trouble to put sed commands in double-quotes as this invites the shell to modify it.

So, since BRE are obsolete, let's (1) switch to Extended Regular Expressions (ERE) using the `-E` switch, (2) put the command in single-quotes, and (3) change `.*?` to `.*`:

```
$ sed -E 's|.*(;).*|SEMICOLON|g' file
SEMICOLON
```

(*Compatibility note:* if you are on a very old linux system, you may need to replace `-E` with `-r`.)

`.*(;).*` matches everything up to the last semicolon on the line, followed by the semicolon, followed by whatever follows the last semicolon.  In other words, if the line contains a semicolon, `.*(;).*` matches the whole line.  That is why the output is just `SEMICOLON`.

Also, `(;)` matches a semicolon and saves it in group 1.  Since we never use group 1 anywhere, this does nothing for us.  We would get the same result with:

```
$ sed -E 's|.*;.*|SEMICOLON|g' file
SEMICOLON
```

If we remove the `.*`, then every `;` will be replaced:

```
$ sed -E 's|;|SEMICOLON|g' file
"The man satSEMICOLON the man criedSEMICOLON" catsSEMICOLON dogsSEMICOLON
```

If we want to replace the last `;` in the first quoted string, we could use:

```
$ sed -E 's|^([^"]*"[^"]*);|\1SEMICOLON|g' file
"The man sat; the man criedSEMICOLON" cats; dogs;
```

If we want to replace all `;` that are within any quoted string on the line, then we are back to the command at the top.

### Strings spanning across lines

Let's consider a test file with a string spanning 2 lines:

```
$ cat file2
"man;" cat "dog
;"; ";man";
```

If you have GNU sed:

```
$ sed -Ez ':a; s/^(([^"]*"[^"]*")*[^"]*"[^"]*);/\1SEMICOLON/; ta' file2
"manSEMICOLON" cat "dog
SEMICOLON"; "SEMICOLONman";
```

In general for any POSIX sed:

```
$ sed -E 'H;1h;$!d;x; :a; s/^(([^"]*"[^"]*")*[^"]*"[^"]*);/\1SEMICOLON/; ta' file2
"manSEMICOLON" cat "dog
SEMICOLON"; "SEMICOLONman";
```

Comment: wrt `(Compatibility note: if you are on a very old linux system, you may need to replace -E with -r.)` - assuming by linux you actually mean UNIX, `-r` is GNU-only while `-E` is GNU plus OSX. The OP said `I'm trying to use sed on Mac OS X` so `-r` won't work and on an older system your sed will have neither option and only support BREs.